# How much of real Greek Mythology does the writer Rick Riordan use?

Tags: greek

So I've noticed that there is this on going book series done by Rick Riordan. Well, he actually has many. Percy Jackson, Apollo, and the Lost Hero. And it got me thinking a bit. How much of mentioned monsters, gods, etc. is actually true, or it it just to enhance his story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some researching about the writer, I've got this answer. It turns out that all of the mentioned gods, titans, monsters, and historic heroes are real. That's right. Any name (except from the modern demigods and Camp Halfblood) is taken from real Greek Mythology. But there's a catch. Rick Riordan may have revived or slightly altered some of the monsters or titans. For example, Typhon was trapped under a mountain in Greek Mythology, but he comes back in Percy Jackson. So does Cronus and many other monsters.

So the answer is yes, all of the characters come from the Greek canon, but the things that they do, and the timelines that they exist in aren't part of the historical canon.

I suggest reading Rick Riordan's guide to Greek gods and heroes, as they provide tons of information on true mythological events.

Comment: The Greek canon is especially rich in that much has survived in written form.  The canon is, in some sense, subsequent generations of story tellers "riffing" on previous stories, adding details or contradicting previous accounts.  *(My favorite contemporary mythographer is [Madeline Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeline_Miller#Early_life).  I'm considering her [Circe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35959740-circe) as a new addition to the canon!)*

Comment: I can't find "Rick Riordan's guide to Greek gods and heroes".  Could you link to the book on Goodreads?

Comment: Any source or explanation for your conclusion? You say this answer comes from researching, but you don't mention your source or your method for determining it